# Gujarati Fonts Support in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, fonts, language-support, input-language

When you will upgrade your operating system from 15.10 to 16.04 Gujarati Newspapers titles are not readable So to resolve these here is a solution
**1.** Download these file shruti.ttf & shruti.woff
**2.** Move to fonts folder of user using command
**3.** sudo mv file_name /usr/share/fonts

Comment: That's great, but please can you edit your post to make a question and answer, rather than including the answer in the question? The way it is now makes it look like your question is unanswered.

Comment: Do you claim that the new Gujarati fonts in 16.04 don't work, or did you just not notice the change? Please see my answer.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Gujarati fonts are available in the Ubuntu archive for 16.04 just like in 15.10, and if you install the Gujarati language, the packages `fonts-gujr`, `fonts-lohit-gujr`, `fonts-samyak-gujr` and `fonts-gujr-extra` are included in the installed language support. The difference is that the previous package `ttf-gujarati-fonts` has been replaced with `fonts-gujr` and friends.